# Отправка письма MODX

Tags: modx

Есть сайт fstt.ru Реализовал отправку письма с помощю formIt, когда использовалась гугловая почта то нормально приходило, а когда поставил info@fstt.ru, письма не приходят. В настройках включил все упоминания про smtpно ефекта не дало. Что можно еще сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Может на хостинге запрещено отправлять письма самому себе, можно попробовать изменить почтовый адрес в поле "От" или сменить дресата.